# Pass the name of the file to a bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to pass the name of a file via a variable to bulk insert/

This does not work:

```
bulk insert XMLfile 
from 
@Name_of_file
with ( rowterminator = ''' + char(10) + ''' )
```

But, this does:

```
bulk insert XMLfile 
from 
'abc.xml'
with ( rowterminator = ''' + char(10) + ''' )
```

How would I go about passing the file name to this statement?

Comment: "Does not work".. you should get into the habit of explaining that.  What's the error?

Comment: how do you set your variable?

Comment: Just added the syntax error and variable type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a variable for the file name. If you look at [BULK INSERT syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx), you will see that file name is a constant. To achieve what you are looking for, you have to use dynamic SQL, i.e. building the query as a string.